# Change heightOfPrevious UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

Is there anyway I can change the height of previous UITableViewCell when setting height for current cell in `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`?

Have two rows in a `UITableView`. When in first row, it will set the default height.. When in row two I want to change the height of first row. Is this possible? If so how?

Thanks,
Bharathi.

Comment: Do you mean when selecting the first row?

Comment: No. When initializing itself...

Comment: can u specify what is your exact requirement. u can find an alternate solution, instead of changing the first row height while you are in second row.

Comment: Okay so why don't use differnt heights for each row instead of changing the height of the first when you are in the second row?
Sounds a bit confusing for me

Comment: @AzzUrr1 and Anish :- I don't want different heights for each row. I have default height set for tableView. When second row is not synced with iCloud, I want to change the first row's Height. So that, the row will align properly to the design. If synced already I don't need to change anything... Did you get my requirement right?

Comment: The answer down should fulifill your requirement. Take a look at it

Answer (score 1):

Try to work with a boolean check if the requirement is fulfilled.
You could do it like this:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  { 

    if (indexPath.row == 0 && !secondRowIsSynced) {
        return otherHeight ;
    }
    else {
        return defaultHeight;
    }
}
```

Comment: No.. I think I haven't conveyed my requirement well. heightForRowAtIndexPath will return height for current row. Thats perfect. As well as I want to change previous row's height too.. Isn't it possible?

Comment: It would advise you: Try it out and look if it does what you want it to do. You can also do it with variables (For example you can always check the upcoming row or something like this)

Answer (score 0):

bharathi:

You have to reload your table in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method of `UITableView`.

You should check that the second row is selected, then reload all the table rows, so all `tableview delegate` and `datasource` methods get called again.

Comment: But she wants to change height during initialization itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called multiple times (once for each row in your table).

If your rows have different heights then you need to determine which row you are on and what height it should have.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    CGFloat height;

    if (0 == indexPath.row) {
        // This is the first row 
        height = // what ever you want
    } else if (1 == indexPath.row) {
        // This is the second row 
        height = // what ever you want
    }

    return height;
}
```

If you later decide that a row needs to be a different height then it is still this method that needs to calculate the correct height to be used for each row. You can force this to be called without reloading the tableView like this

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```